# Android Studio: Updating multiple buttons' backgrounds one by one when clicking a button

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, onclicklistener, background-color

I am writing here because I have a very annoying problem in Android Studio.
My "application" is extremely simple, one page with 13 button; All I want is simple: update the first twelve buttons one by one when I click the 13th button.
I would like to see buttons updating with a little interval between each of them, but I can't understand how to do it.
I tried many tricks inside the "onClick" method but I can not figure out how to solve it; what I obtain is that after some time (the time obtained adding up the various "sleep" I put in the function) all the buttons become colored at the same time.
I put my last attempt, but if you have any other way to do that I am willing to change the way to proceed.

```
int[] buttonIDs = new int[] {R.id.button1, R.id.button2, R.id.button3, R.id.button4, R.id.button5, R.id.button6, R.id.button7,
        R.id.button8, R.id.button9, R.id.button10, R.id.button11, R.id.button12 };
int currentI = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button goButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button13);

    goButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (currentI < buttonIDs.length) {
                Button b = (Button) findViewById(buttonIDs[currentI]);
                b.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF22FF"));
                currentI++;

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Thread t = new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        goButton.performClick();
                    }
                };

                t.start();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

The result of this attempt is that the first button become colored and then I get "Application has stopped" error on the Android Emulator.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should not sleep in on the UI thread. This simply stops the UI from responding.

Comment: Even if I remove it the application crashes. Besides I need a way to get the buttons colored one by one, for that reason I put a sleep (I've even tried to put "sleep" inside the method "run" of the thread t, but it does not change anything.

Comment: The UI thread is responsible for making tree changes to the buttons. By sleeping the UI thread you are blocking these changes from taking effect. So this is definitely not the correct solution. See the two answers below for some suggestions. Neither are complete, but hopefully they will help you in the general right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Do something after 1000ms
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This seems close to what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea here is that you need to create a new thread which signals the UI thread to update each button. In between each update, the new thread needs to wait until the UI has a chance to perform the update. I'm not very experienced with this kind of thing. You can most likely do this with a Handler. There might be more high-level tools you can use instead, but I'm not sure.

You definitely do not want to sleep the UI thread. This will only cause the UI to become unresponsive.